# How to kill subprocesses with another command python

Tags: python, server, raspberry-pi, subprocess, kill

I am running two subprocesses in a Python server script. The purpose of the subprocesses is to stream video from my Raspberry Pi.

My question is how to kill the subprocesses when another command is sent to the server. I am currently using Popen() to start the subprocesses.

This is my code for when the server receives the command "startStream". I am using Twisted library as server protocol.

```
class Echo(Protocol):
   def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "data is ", data

        if data == "startStream":
            p = subprocess.Popen("raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &", shell=True)
            pn = subprocess.Popen("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i %s -o %s &" % (x,y), shell=True)
```

What I would like is something like this.

```
if data == "startStream":
        p = subprocess.Popen("raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &", shell=True)
        pn = subprocess.Popen("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i %s -o %s &" % (x,y), shell=True)
elif data == "stopStream":
        os.kill(p.pid)
        os.kill(pn.pid)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is that p and pn is not accessible when stopStream is called upon. I am used to be working with Java where I could've just declared the processes as global variables and then access them from anywhere but apparently that doesn't work in Python.

Comment: Also the module has no attribute terminate

Comment: right, `terminate` might only work with threads...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some context here, but basically server would do something like:

```
while True:
    data = wait_for_request()
    if data == 'startStream':
        p = subprocess.Popen("raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &", shell=True)
        pn = subprocess.Popen("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i %s -o %s &" % (x,y), shell=True)
    elif data == 'stopStream':
        p.terminate()
        pn.terminate()
```

The crucial part is that names `p` and `pn` exists in same scope and therefore they are accessible without using any kind of global state. If your code structure is different, you need to outline it in question.

Since `data_received` has it's own scope on each call, you need to pass a reference to your Popen object in different way.
Fortunately, you may keep references in the class instance.

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    if data=='startStream':
        self.p = subprocess.Popen()  # ...
        self.pn = subprocess.Popen()  # ...
    elif data=='stopStream':
        self.p.terminate()
        self.pn.terminate()
```

[`Popen.terminate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) is available from Python 2.6 and should work just fine - I'm not sure what's an issue in question's comments.

Comment: See my updated code. That's how my server code currently looks.

Comment: I can't get it to work. What do you mean by passing a reference to my Popen object?

Comment: It just doesn't stop. I have to manually cancel it with ctrl+c in the terminal in order to close the camera.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to kill all subprocesses?

Comment: `Popen.terminate`: _Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child._  `Popen.kill`: _Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child. On Windows kill() is an alias for terminate()._